# how to select element with getByTestId that also has specific value with react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

In react, I am mapping out some elements from an array. For example

```
{options.map((option)=>{
  return <div data-testid="option">{option}</div>
})
```

I have multiple tests where I want to select an option (without knowing what the textContent of the option is) so I used `data-testid="option"` and select with `screenGetAllByTestId('option')[0]` to select the first option...

However, there are some times that I know what particular option I want, and I want to `getByTestId` but because they all share the same data-testid its a bit harder.

What I'm trying to do, is something similar to this pseudo code:

`screen.getAllByTestId('option').getByText("Apples")`

which will get all the options, but then get the specific one that has Apples as text

Comment: Did you try https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/?

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom matcher functions too, like:

```js
screen.getByText((content, element) => {
  return element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span' && content.startsWith('Hello')
})
```

[From the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#textmatch-examples)

I think in your case, that translates to:

```js
screen.getByText((content, element) => {
  return element.getAttribute('data-testid').toLowerCase() === 'option' && content === 'Apples'
})
```

An even better solution might be to have legible text labels attached to each group of options, so your tests could say:

```js
// Find your menu / list header
const fruitsListHeader = screen.getByText('Fruits list');

// Find the menu or whatever it's in
// You can use plain old query selectors
const fruitsList = fruitsListHeader.closest('[role="menu"]')

// Look for your option in the right place, instead of 
// praying there are no duplicated options on the page.
const appleOption = within(fruitsList.closest('[role="menu"))
  .getByText('Apples');
```

[`within` docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/)